# Passed variable to an array dimension error

Tags: c

I have used `lenA` and `lenB` of `int` type in my program. When i passed this variable to  `consensus_a[]` or `consensus_b[]`, this error shown:

```
expression must have a constant value.
```

How can i pass these variables (`lenA` or `lenB`) to char `consensus_a[]` or `consensus_b[]`.

A small part of my program:

```
    int lenA=10, lenB=15;
    char consensus_a[lenA],consensus_b[lenB];
```

Comment: The code in the loop doesn't have anything to do with the declarations of the arrays below.

Comment: The code is valid `C` code. Variable length arrays are part of `C99` standard. Are you compiling it as a C++ code ?

Comment: Also, what compiler do you use? Variable length array declaration was introduced in C99, if the compiler doesn't compile in C99 (or later standard) mode then that you can not use declarations like that.

Comment: Where are lenA,lenB defined?

Comment: @mahdimb, please show your compiler version in your question, it will clear up a lot of confusion in the answers and comments.

Comment: If you're writing C code, the proper solution would be to use a proper C compiler. Microsoft abandoned C for some time now, and only ships an old compiler. Try instead something like Code Blocks (http://www.codeblocks.org) or Orwell Dev-C++ (http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com) which come with GCC as their compiler, which supports C99 very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be running a compiler that does not comply with C99 (possibly because it's older than that) (as already stated, the code should compile with a C99 compliant compiler).

With these compilers, for arrays in the form

```
char a[x];
```

`x` needs to be constant.

**You could use `const`:**

```
const int lenA=10, lenB=15;
char consensus_a[lenA],consensus_b[lenB];
```

**Or `enum`:**

```
enum
{
  lenA = 10,
  lenB = 15
};
char consensus_a[lenA], consensus_b[lenB];
```

**Or `#define`:**

```
#define lenA 10
#define lenB 15
char consensus_a[lenA], consensus_b[lenB];
```

**Or `malloc` (if you don't want them to be constant):**

```
char *consensus_a = malloc(lenA),
     *consensus_b = malloc(lenB);
```

Technically it would be:

```
char *consensus_a = malloc(lenA*sizeof(char)),
     *consensus_b = malloc(lenB*sizeof(char));
```

but `sizeof(char)` is 1, so including the term is unnecessary.

**When using `malloc`, do remember to also `free` them after using them:**

```
free(consensus_a);
free(consensus_b);
```

Comment: i used char *consensus_a = (char*)malloc(lenA*sizeof(char)) and char *consensus_b = (char*)malloc(lenB*sizeof(char)). it's works. thanks:-)

Answer (score 0):

You compiler complains that you're trying to declare an array with variable length. That's not possible for compiler not complying to C99 standard or newer. Use constant value instead of `lenA`/`lenB`.

Comment: Variable length arrays are part of `C99` standard.

Comment: Yes you can. Since 14 years now. It's a long time.

Comment: Apparently, not for OP. Or for MSVC. @NikosC. The question is not about knowing one standard or the other.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but maybe clarifying the answer would be nice. Like, making sure that C99 is enabled in the compiler, or not using MSVC :-)

Comment: @mahdimb, MSVC only supports C89.  It does not support C99 fully.

Comment: Replace `int lenA=10, lenB=15;` with `const int lenA=10, lenB=15;` - this should solve your problem.